# In Azure I wanted to get sku list for a specific VM using Python SDK

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, azure-sdk-python

As per my requirement using Azure Python SDK I want to get Azure VM family details if the existing VM belongs to N servies family or something else.

Below is the code which I am using.

```
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

client_id = "sp appId"
secret = "sp password"
tenant = "sp tenant"
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id = client_id,
        secret = secret,
        tenant = tenant
)

Subscription_Id = ''
compute_client =ComputeManagementClient(credentials,Subscription_Id)
resource_group_name='Networking-WebApp-AppGW-V1-E2ESSL'
virtual_machine_scale_set_name='VMSS'
results = compute_client.resource_skus.list(raw=True)
resourceSkusList = [result.as_dict() for result in results]
r=json.dumps(resourceSkusList)
print(r)
```

But here above code gives me details of all available resource SKUs and I wanted the resource SKU on the basis of a VM names as I want to check if a particular VM belongs to which family.

Could anyone help me in achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

The SkuOperations class contains a [list()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-storage/azure.mgmt.storage.v2019_06_01.operations.skusoperations?view=azure-python#list---kwargs-) method starting with `azure-mgmt-storage==16.0.0`. You can use a set to get rid of duplicate SKU names since the method will return numerous SKUs for each area and storage type it supports.

```py
from azure.mgmt.storage import StorageManagementClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

storage_client = StorageManagementClient(
    credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
    subscription_id="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
)

skus = {sku.name for sku in storage_client.skus.list()}

for sku in skus:
print(sku)
```

Iterate the set for good format:

```py
for sku in skus:
    print(sku)
```

Which outputs the SKUs on newlines like so:

```py
Standard_LRS
Standard_RAGRS
Standard_RAGZRS
Standard_ZRS
Premium_LRS
Standard_GRS
Standard_GZRS
Premium_ZRS
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. but it seems this is for storage type. But I want VM instance type. Here I want to verify if my VM belongs to GPU VM type or General purpose. So, how can I do it for a specific VM?

Answer (score 0):

2+ years later there still isn't an easy option for doing this. There are 2 ways that I know of:

**Option 1**

Weirdly enough it's located in [azure.mgmt.batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-batch/azure.mgmt.batch.operations.locationoperations?view=azure-python#azure-mgmt-batch-operations-locationoperations-list-supported-virtual-machine-skus), you have to search by location and look up your vm's vm_size property:

```
from azure.mgmt.batch import BatchManagementClient

location = "your vm's location"
subscription_id = "your subscription id"

batch_client = BatchManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
supported_skus = [sku for sku in 
batch_client.location.list_supported_virtual_machine_skus(location)]
```

For some reason this doesn't return data for the Standard_B family, but then you have option 2.

**Option 2**

Use azure's cli and run `az vm list-sku`, the result is a ~73MB json and you can look your machine's sku by its location and vm_size there